# Azure Queue duplicate items

Tags: azure, azure-queues

Does anyone see a problem with this code? I have a single Azure Queue in operation that I write to after each transaction on a Web Application. The queue is only called once per transaction, but items sometimes appear more than once - 10 duplicates in some cases. This is sporadic and happens rarely, but it is annoying nonetheless.

```
public async ActionResult DoWork()
{
//Carry out some processing

    string jsonMessage = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(MyDataObject);
    await storageAccess.AddItemToQueue(new CloudQueueMessage(jsonMessage));
}




public async Task AddItemToQueue(CloudQueueMessage message)
{

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);

            // Create the blob client.
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("outbox");

        await queue.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        await queue.AddMessageAsync(message);
}
```

If there is a timeout or a warning, could the AddMessageAsync method be trying to send it again until it succeeds?

Inspecting the queue, the items might look like this, where I have 3 items, all containing the same MyObject1 inserted well after the transaction closed.

```
1. ksasdsad-asdsad-asdsads-s222  12:05  MyObject1
2. sadadsd-weqwe-sdddsd-e21323   12:10  MyObject1
3. 32323-asdsads-2123213-sddwe   12:30  MyObject1
```

Comment: the above code looks okay, but this does not give an entire picture - how is this called etc. How is this set up, like a web job or simply when you web app is hot? Is your web application replicated over regions - meaning is there two instances of the same web app that is load balanced? need more information.

Comment: Its a Shared Web App set to one instance, auto-scale disabled. Someone clicks a button on a website and that triggers a workflow of sequential tasks, finishing with that code above to add an item to a queue - like a receipt. There's no load balancing or switching through a VIP, so only one path to get to that code above. The message GUIDs are all unique and maybe a few minutes apart, but the content of the CloudMessage is a duplicate.

Comment: Couple of things here -> 1) Azure Queue does *NOT* do a duplicate detection for you. You need to manage it on the calling code, in this case your button event handler. 2) Are you sure these duplicate messages are from the same session? Could it not be possible two users might have had triggered a similar workflow. e.g. Purchased the same item?

Comment: Good points. I guess I can add a check before adding to the queue just in case - but the generation of transaction ids is atomic - and each of the messages has the same transaction id. Which is why I was wondering if there wasn't some sort of "acknowledgement" after writing to the queue, then it would try again. But I guess that is not the case

Comment: Sure,by transactionId , I guess you mean - the Id generated by your code (may be the Id of the transaction that took place ) so once that is part of the Azure Queue Message Body : you can do two things 1) Check the approximate count of the queued messages before and after to see if it got pushed  2) Then on the listener of the Queued messages, check if the `transactionId` which is part of the `CloudMessage` has been processed - am hoping you have a boolean/flag set for all processed ones, if yes, then do not process the queued message (duplicate in this case).

Comment: Hey all - comments aren't the place to bury more information. The original question should be edited. Including code that shows how you're reading/deleting queue items.

Comment: I have same issue

Comment: @Jinesh - In the end I moved to a Table from a Queue which prevented duplicates (for free). I never found a solution for the duplicates and couldn't see how my execution flow would be re-inserting a duplicate